# Query to obtain average each 30 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i calculate average of each 30 second? The following is the table structure

```
    Price  TTime
```

every minute 5-60 records inserted. The time is inserted by getDate(). I have to calculate average of every 30 seconds.

Comment: you  can also use oracle triggers

Comment: @john: Didn't know they also made a version for SQL Server. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to do 2 things:

- Create a column (in your SELECT result, not in the table) that contains the time in half-minutes;
- calculate the average of Price using AVG(Price) and GROUP BY:

  ```
  SELECT <function returning half minutes from TTime> AS HalfMinute, AVG(Price) FROM <Table> GROUP BY HalfMinute`
  ```

I don't know SQL Server's time functions. If you can get the time returned in seconds, you could go with SECONDS/30. Maybe someone else can step in with details here.

Comment: Smotricz,
at present i am calculating for every one minute using following query. 

select AVG(Price),DatePart(mi,ttime) from TABLE1 group by DatePart(mi,ttime) Order by 2

DatePart(s,ttime) would give me second part of date. complicated part is each 30 second.

Comment: Ah, together we can lick this. I'd suggest Tomalak's solution, but substitute Floor(SECOND(TTIME) / 30) as the last part of the grouping expression.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(Price)   AS AvgPrice, 
  COUNT(Price) AS CountPrice,
  MIN(TTIME)   AS PeriodBegin,
  (SECOND(TTime) % 30) * 30 AS PeriodType  /* either 0 or 30 */
FROM 
  PriceTable
GROUP BY
  YEAR(TTime), MONTH(TTime), DAY(TTime), HOUR(TTime), MINUTE(TTime)
  SECOND(TTime) % 30  /* either 0 or 1 */
ORDER BY
 MIN(TTime)
```

In place of:

```
GROUP BY
  YEAR(TTime), MONTH(TTime), DAY(TTime), HOUR(TTime), MINUTE(TTime)
```

you could also use, for example:

```
GROUP BY
  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, TTime, 120), 16)
```

In any case these are operation that invoke a table scan, since they are not indexable. A WHERE clause to determine the valid TTime range is advisable.

You could also make a column that contains the calculated date (`'…:00.000'` or `'…:30.000'`) and fill that on INSERT with help of a trigger. Place an index on it, GROUP BY it, done.

Comment: Thaks guys,
Unfortunatly it is not for reporting purpose. I have to calculate correlation. a third column token is there, on which, correlation would be calculated.